# form:select does not work in edit mode if there multiple select in Spring MVC project

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have multiple select input in my form it work fine if i selected one item then edited the object but it does not work if i have selected two items then try edit my object i found no item selected.

```html
<tr>
 <td><form:label path="languages"><spring:message code="usher.languages"/></form:label><span class="required"/></td>
 <td><form:select path="languages" items="${languages}" multiple="true" styleId="languages"/></td>
</tr>
```

If i selected one item it works fine in edit mode.

But if i selected two items the try to edit my object, there is no item selected.

I added my object attribute as below

> List languages = new ArrayList();
>           languages.add("English");
>           languages.add("French");
>           languages.add("German");
>           languages.add("None");
>           model.addObject("languages", languages);

Any idea to solve this issue?